# Meteor couldn't hold a session's value among pages

Tags: meteor

I'm facing a problem that Meteor couldn't hold a session's value if a Web page is moved to a other Web page. I'm new for Meteor, maybe I'm misusing.
How do I handle session's value among pages? I want to keep session's value even if the page move to the other page or browser is reloaded.

I'm planing to build a Web application using Javascript framework such as Meteor, Mojito, and Express (Node.js) and testing them before developing.

I'm using Meteor version 0.5.2 (6635ae1007) and
Chrome version 23.0.1271.95.

Here is a test code and steps for test:

(1) Click the 'TEST' button:

This changes 'Result is' labels to 'Result is OK'.

(2) Click the 'Back to Top page' link or reload the browser:

I want to hold the label 'Result is OK' but it goes back to 'Result is'.
It means session value is undefined.

test.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.test.result = function() {
    var result = Session.get('TEST');
    console.log('Result: %s', result);
    return result;
  }

  Template.test.events({
    'click' : function() {
        Session.set('TEST', 'OK');
    }
  });
}
```

test.html

```
<head>
  <title>sample-session</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Session Test</h1>
  <a href="./">Back to Top page<a/><br/>
  {{> test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <input type="button" value="TEST"></input><br/>
  Result is {{result}}.
</template>
```

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE** Meteor now has a [Session.setDefault](http://docs.meteor.com/#session_set_default) method that does exactly what you're expecting.

**Original Answer Below**

The `session` object in meteor is **fundamentally different** from the `session` concept in other frameworks (Rails/ASP.NET MVC/PHP) -- its primary function in Meteor is to serve as a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#session) for *client side* code.

It is **not** designed to do what you're expecting above -- as soon as your link fires, the client context is wiped, and any client-side session values are gone. Meteor apps aren't designed for navigation in the traditional sense, so that's why this seems so confusing. It's completely understandable :)

Instead of approaching navigation in the traditional sense, I suggest you take a look at [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), which helps ease the transition between traditional and a more meteoresque approach.

If you do need to persist data the way you're describing above, you'll want to look into the [amplify smart package](http://docs.meteor.com/#amplify) for persisting data on the client locally.

TIP: as you learn about Meteor in [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/), pay very close attention to the designation of client / server / anywhere in the upper right of each segment.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Now I understand the word 'session' in Meteor. I will check meteor-router and amplify smart package you suggested above.